# How to use IDisposable pattern on Windows Form

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've read about IDisposable pattern on this [article](http://lostechies.com/chrispatterson/2012/11/29/idisposable-done-right/) and want to implement it in my windows form application. As we know that in windows form .Designer.cs class there is already Dispose method

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

and in .cs class I'm using Typed Dataset to read and save the data.

```
public partial class frmCustomerList
{
    private MyTypedDataSet ds = new MyTypedDataSet();
    ...
}
```

So, how to implement `IDisposable` to dispose MyTypedDataSet? If I implement `IDisposable` in frmCustomerList and implement its interface

```
public partial class frmCustomerList : IDisposable
{
    private MyTypedDataSet ds = new MyTypedDataSet();
    void Dispose()
    {
       ds.Dispose();
    }
}
```

what about `Dispose(bool disposing)` method in .Designer.cs?

Comment: Why do you need to dispose `MyTypedDataSet`?

Comment: I don't think you need `IDisposable` on the form. Unless you're holding a bunch of unmanaged memory, you don't need to dispose it.

Comment: Why do you want to implement `IDisposable` on a form? Surely you could just respond to the `FormClosed` event to do your clean up?

Comment: @BenAaronson because I want to clean up DataSet, in my opinion if it is not wrong, if I work with many forms and I don't dispose the DataSet this could cause the application to be slow

Comment: @Enigmativity yes I can clean up any resources (DataSet) at FormClosed but I just wanna know what's the appropriate way?

Comment: @Willy - `FormClosed` (or `FormClosing`) would be the appropriate way. I wouldn't recommend changing the designer code to make `IDisposable` work.

Comment: @Willy The garbage collector will do that for you. Just make sure that no references to the dataset are being held after you're done with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would dispose any members of the form using one of the forms events such as

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosed(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);

    if (ds != null)
        ds.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mick, why do you use protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) rather than private void frmCustomerList_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) ? Is there any concern?

Comment: You can use either.  There should be no functional difference.  Subscribing to the closed event is actually probably safer as you might forget to call the base class method which will cause issues.

Comment: This works as long as the form is opened. A Form can be created (i.e. go through its constructor) without ever being shown.

Answer (score 14):

If you look in the Designer.cs file and look ***below*** the dispose method you will see this

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
```

Only `InializeComponent()` is warned about not modifing. You can **cut** (not copy) and paste the `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` out of the designer file and move it in your main code file without worry, just be sure to leave the `components.Dispose();` part in as any disposable objects you add through the designer will be put in that collection for disposing.

```
public partial class frmCustomerList
{
    private MyTypedDataSet ds = new MyTypedDataSet();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ds.Dispose();

        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    //The rest of your frmCustomerList.cs file.
}
```

Comment: This is a seriously bad idea.  Changing designer generated code is not a good idea, it's a very bad one

Comment: @Mick Visual studio is desgined to handle this change. I would never reccomend changing anything inside the `#region Windows Form Designer generated code` region that is why they put the `Dispose()` function outside of the region.

Comment: I still wouldn't touch the Designer.cs regardless of regions within the file, the file is generated by the designer.  Changes to the file can easily be lost and there are other ways to solve this which don't involve editing the file.

Comment: This is the better answer for me, since I don't need to supress CA2213. Upvote. Thanks Scott.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... this is the actual correct method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not care about disposing your class except if you have unmanaged resources. Here is an example where it actually useful:

```
public class ComplexResourceHolder : IDisposable
{

    private IntPtr buffer; // unmanaged memory buffer
    private SafeHandle resource; // disposable handle to a resource

    public IntPtr Buffer { get { return buffer; } set { buffer = value; } }

    public ComplexResourceHolder()
    {
        this.buffer = ... // allocates memory
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory
    if (disposing)
    { 
        // release other disposable objects
        if (resource!= null)
           resource.Dispose();
    }
}

~ ComplexResourceHolder(){
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose(){
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

}

Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for better understanding of Dispose(bool) finalizer override. And [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about unmanaged resources will be useful as well because this is the first reason why you should use IDisposable.

You might wonder to use constructions like below if the class inherits IDisposable:

```
using (ComplexResourceHolder crh = new ComplexResourceHolder())
{
    //Do something with buffer for an instance
    //crh.Buffer =
}
```

Dispose method will be called automatically after closing tag '}'.

Comment: This is misleading, if a member of a class implements dispose, you should implement dispose on the class, not just when you class directly deals with unmanaged resources. Even with managed resources, classes often implement dispose to ensure timely collection of managed resources that are expensive

Comment: Garbage collector will do all the work as fast as he can. Even if you are calling GC.SuppressFinalize(this) it doesn't mean GC will collect it immediately. It will collect whenever GC thinks he can collect it. I have tested memory changes after using disposing on managed resources and without. The timings almost the same.

Comment: Most of .NET classes don't implement IDisposable. Why? Because it unnecessary.

Comment: All Controls from System.Windows.Forms implement IDisposable. That's why all forms contain Dispose method.

Comment: Well we're programming in parallel universes.  If I see an object being instantiated that implements IDispose and the owning object never calls Dispose on that object, or it's not wrapped in a using statement, that's a bug in my books.

I'll go even further and mention that the GC needs help to garbage collect, especially on platforms like windows phone and windows CE.  Implementing Dispose and decoupling objects (setting variables to null) does make a difference. Circular dependencies can create blocks of classes that never get collected.

Comment: I don't think you're thinking is that uncommon, I've seen large memory leaks in many .NET applications written by people who would probably agree with you.  A good example is Visual Studio itself, it's written in .NET, on my machine it opens consuming 100K, you work with it for a day, even after closing every file, it can take up 2 gigs. I wouldn't hire a .NET Developer who doesn't believe .NET apps can leak managed memory .

Comment: I agree your 2 posts above. But I have tried to answer **specifically** to this topic. @Willy didn't mention what a class he wanted to be disposed, what platform he works etc. So because of that I found it unnecessary to implement IDisposable. My point is just you **must** use Dispose when you actually have memory leaks etc., but it doesn't mean you need to implement IDisposable for each class you have. :D